# Visual studio project build dependencies with no references?

Tags: visual-studio, dependencies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting up a build dependency without using a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100674/setting-up-a-build-dependency-without-using-a-reference)

Is it possible to set a project to force another project to be built, but without having to setup a reference?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Right-click on your solution and choose `Project dependencies`. This allows you to set a build time dependency between projects, without referencing.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the solution and select "Build Order". All the projects need to be part of that solution though, even if they do not reference on another.