# Build another project by prebuild event without adding reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, pre-build-event

I am copying .exe file form a separate to my main project's folder on prebuild event but I need to build that project before build my main project so i want to build that project on prebuild event of my main project.

Comment: A better solution (if read in 2018) would be to setup a project dependency, see instructions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2868986/2193151

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not that this is the best solution, but it will definitely work for what you want to do: Put the below into your pre-build event

`"$(VS100COMNTOOLS)..\IDE\devenv" "csproj location OR sln location" /Rebuild "configuration required if you have more than configuration ex: Debug|x64"`

Comment: Thank for this! I use Visual studio 2015 and now it will looks like  
`"$(DevEnvDir)\devenv"  "csproj location OR sln location" /Rebuild "configuration required if you have more than configuration ex: Debug|x64"`

Answer (score 13):

This is what worked for me:

```
"$(DevEnvDir)devenv" "$(SolutionDir)MySolution.sln" /Build $(configuration) /project "$(SolutionDir)MyProjectFolder\MyProject.csproj"
```

Here `$(DevEnvDir)`, `$(SolutionDir)`, and `$(configuration)` are [Visual Studio Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx), so this command will be translated into:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv" "D:\Learning\MySolutionFolder\MySolutionName.sln" /Build Debug /project "D:\Learning\MySolutionFolder\MyProjectFolder\MyProject.csproj"
```

Comment: $(DevEnvDir) and $(SolutionDir) should NOT be followed by \ because the variables end with \

Answer (score 0):

```
"$(DevEnvDir)devenv" "$(SolutionPath)" /Rebuild $(configuration) /project "$(SolutionDir)MyProjectFolder\MyProject.csproj"
```

Tested now on Visual Studio Community 16.11.1

Answer (score 0):

Using the below command in visual studio 2019, build is faster with msbuild as compared to "$(DevEnvDir)devenv".

**msbuild "$(SolutionDir)Sample.sln" /p:configuration=$(configuration)**