# Visual Studio C++ Creating executable in executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want to create 2 executable with only 1 executable. How can i do that in Visual Studio 2015? I looked in internet but couldnt find something. Is there any way i can do that without wizard? Simply there will be 2 project in  1 solution and project1's exe will create project2's exe. Or something that will do what i want.

The purpose is user will not have to download 2 separate  exe, he will only download 1 and otherone will be created beside exe1( both program has different purposes, so exe1 will not be onl for creating exe2)

Comment: Your question makes no sense. "How can I buy 2 cars with only 1 car?" "How can I bake 2 cakes with only 1 cake?"

Comment: Why do you think you need to produce a second executable? What is the function of the first one, and what is the function of the second one.

Comment: The first one will only run 1 time and the second one will be a service. First one has a GUI also. And i want to do with this way if its possible rather then leaving a sign when program ran first time and it can be service anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Use CreateProcess in first executable to create second process from another executaable.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512(v=vs.85).aspx

If you need two output from one project:
use post build events:

1- Make a copy of output.

2- Change whatever you want to change.

3- Build same project again:
[Build another project by prebuild event without adding reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895948/build-another-project-by-prebuild-event-without-adding-reference)
In your case another project is the same project.

Comment: I couldnt tell what i need i think. I want them to be independent from each other. When exe1 ran, it will produce the exe2 which is a project in same solution with exe1. And their contents are different.

Comment: Then you just need CreateProcess with the path of second executable.

Comment: Hmm isnt there any chance that user only will open 1 exe and other one will  be created ?

Comment: Yes, CreateProcess will do that for you in first executable. You need to pass the path for second executable to this function.