# Build .net core project by postbuild event in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, .net-core, visual-studio-2017, post-build-event

I have project `A` which has dependency on project `B` but there is no reference from `B` to `A`. I want build and copy assemblies in `bin folder` of project `B` to `bin folder` of project `A`. how can I do this with post build event and `dotnet msbuild`.

I found this link but it works for VS 2015 and below and MS-Build:

[Build another project by prebuild event without adding reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13301439/1385614)

Comment: what about this issue? Would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @Leo-MSFT your solution works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I do this with post build event and dotnet msbuild

You can add **Build task** and **copy task** in the post build event in project A to achieve your request:

```
"$(MSBuildBinPath)\MSBuild.exe" "$(SolutionDir)ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj"
 xcopy.exe "$(SolutionDir)ProjectB\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\ProjectB.dll" "$(SolutionDir)ProjectA\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1"
```

If you have multiple assemblies in the bin folder of project B, you can also use the **Wildcard** to copy the assemblies, like

`xcopy.exe "$(SolutionDir)ProjectB\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\*.dll`

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what worked for me. It comes from: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/677

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="if not exist $(OutDir)..\..\..\..\build  mkdir $(OutDir)..\..\..\..\build" />
    <Exec Command="copy $(OutDir)$(TargetName).dll $(OutDir)..\..\..\..\build\$(TargetName).dll /Y" />
    <Exec Command="copy $(OutDir)$(TargetName).pdb $(OutDir)..\..\..\..\build\$(TargetName).pdb /Y" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Great answer but there is a typo "if not exist $(OutDir)..\..\..\.\build" has a missing "." just before build. Should be "if not exist $(OutDir)..\..\..\..\build"